# is there a python module can output to teminal like linux "top" or "more"?

Tags: python, terminal

May I know is there a such module in python?

Basically I need print database table records to terminal in python supporting page-up and page-down key press.

Also I need a highlighted title bar on top of the screen looks like "top" output, and the output will auto scale to fit the terminal window resize.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic terminal printing with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122385/dynamic-terminal-printing-with-python)

Comment: thanks, curses may hard to use for me, I found another one Urwid, but it is still not simple enough......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this, might be helpful:

- http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html

Also, take a look at these question:

- [Text Progress Bar in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console)

and a link from it:

- http://nadiana.com/animated-terminal-progress-bar-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Python's [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) module is a wrapper around GNU's [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) C library, which is what top uses.