# Output to the same line overwriting previous output?

Tags: python, refresh, progress-bar

I am writing an FTP downloader. Part of to the code is something like this:

```
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file_name, process)
```

I am calling function process to handle the callback:

```
def process(data):
    print os.path.getsize(file_name)/1024, 'KB / ', size, 'KB downloaded!'
    file.write(data)
```

and output is something like this:

```
1784  KB / KB 1829 downloaded!
1788  KB / KB 1829 downloaded!
etc...
```

but I want it to print this line and next time reprint/refresh it so it will only show it once and I will see progress of that download.

How can it be done?

Comment: Duplicate of [*Text progress bar in the console*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3173320).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text Progress Bar in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console)

Comment: This is in no way a duplicate of "Text progress bar in the console."
It's a similar problem, but not the same.
Washing a dog, and washing a cat are similar, they are both mammals.  Washing a cat always requires large amounts of chain mail, where washing a dog is usually one of 8 different scenarios.

Comment: Although all the answers will print on the same line, they may not truly overwrite a line if the subsequent line happens to be shorter. Using field width specifiers for **all** the variables being printed will ensure that as well. For example, if using f-strings, `print(f'\r{filename:<30s} {progress<6d} downloaded', end='', flush=True)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Answer (score 308, accepted):

Here's code for Python 3.x:

```
print(os.path.getsize(file_name)/1024+'KB / '+size+' KB downloaded!', end='\r')
```

The `end=` keyword is what does the work here -- by default, `print()` ends in a newline (`\n`) character, but this can be replaced with a different string. In this case, ending the line with a carriage return instead returns the cursor to the start of the current line. Thus, there's no need to import the `sys` module for this sort of simple usage. `print()` actually has [a number of keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#print) which can be used to greatly simplify code.

To use the same code on Python 2.6+, put the following line at the top of the file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Note that the print function can also be used in python 2.6+ by adding the following import at the top of the file : `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: in python < 3.0 a comma at the end of the statement will prevent a "\n":
  `print "foo",`
However you still need to flush after that to see the change:
`sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: I found I needed to include the `\r` at the start of the string, and set `end=''` instead to get this to work. I don't think my terminal likes it when I end with `\r`

Comment: In all current Python 3 releases, you can add `flush=True` to the `print()` function to ensure the buffer is flushed (the standard line buffer only would flush when a `\n` newline is written).

Comment: In a jupyter notebook, using the `\r` at the beginning and `end=''` worked best and smoothest.  Using `flush=True` with `\r` at the end if the string and `end='\r'` also worked but was not smooth & erased the line& its linefeed.

Comment: @Kudzu: What if instead of one print, I have several prints and I want all of them to act this way?. If I change all print() this way, one will over write all others (They are in a loop, one in the outer loop and two in an inner loop)

Comment: Note that this will not work correctly with shells like IDLE and Spyder, but using `sys.stdout` will.

Comment: @Jezzamon has the right answer.

Comment: If anyone else is having a bug with this not working, look for a subprocess.popen in your code. It seems to print a newline even if it looks like the command has no output. `stdout=file` will fix it.

Comment: This answer would be more clear if you tried to print something simple like "Hello World" instead of reusing the code from the question. At first sight it's not clear that it's `end='\r'` that's the important part, since `os.path.getsize` etc clutters the code.

Answer (score 47):

If all you want to do is change a single line, use `\r`. `\r` means carriage return. It's effect is solely to put the caret back at the start of the current line. It does not erase anything. Similarly, `\b` can be used to go one character backward. (some terminals may not support all those features)

```
import sys

def process(data):
    size_str = os.path.getsize(file_name)/1024, 'KB / ', size, 'KB downloaded!'
    sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % size_str)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: `sys.stdout.write('%s\r', size_str')` i think you meant `sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % size_str)` but it doesnt work.

Comment: @Adrien:  Cool, added that. @Kristian: Thanks, updated that, it was pretty late.

Comment: Also note you can still use `print` instead of `sys.stdout.write` if you prefer: `print size_str + "\r",` works fine. The `,` at the end of the print statement suppresses the newline; `sys.stdout.flush()` is still needed

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at the [curses module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) and the [curses module HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html).

Really basic example:

```
import time
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()

stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Hello")
stdscr.refresh()

time.sleep(1)

stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "World! (with curses)")
stdscr.refresh()
```

Comment: unfortunately, curses is only available on Unix. the OP did not tell us which operating system his application is targeting...

Comment: I'm so used to work under Linux that I didn't even notice the warning about the module being only for UNIX in the module docs.. Thanks for pointing that out, @Adrien.

Comment: @AdrienPlisson, I know that this question was made years ago but, you can actually get Curses onto Windows: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses

Comment: When I pasted this into my Python interpreter, my terminal became fubar. Exiting from the interpreter did not help. WTF?!

Comment: Use [`clrtoeol`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311594/2192488) for **when the second line is shorter than the first.**

Comment: If you're using Jupyter, this approach may mangle your kernel.

Answer (score 14):

Here's my little class that can reprint blocks of text. It properly clears the previous text so you can overwrite your old text with shorter new text without creating a mess.

```
import re, sys

class Reprinter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = ''

    def moveup(self, lines):
        for _ in range(lines):
            sys.stdout.write("\x1b[A")

    def reprint(self, text):
        # Clear previous text by overwritig non-spaces with spaces
        self.moveup(self.text.count("\n"))
        sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r"[^\s]", " ", self.text))

        # Print new text
        lines = min(self.text.count("\n"), text.count("\n"))
        self.moveup(lines)
        sys.stdout.write(text)
        self.text = text

reprinter = Reprinter()

reprinter.reprint("Foobar\nBazbar")
reprinter.reprint("Foo\nbar")
```

Comment: This will not work in Windows up to Windows 10, because Windows 10 is the first windows to support those control characters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: Thank you this was a great starting point. I had issues with this implementation in Python 3.8 so wrote a new one with bugfixes, see my answer.

Answer (score 13):

I am using spyder 3.3.1 - windows 7 - python 3.6
although flush may not be needed.
based on this posting - https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3437

```
   #works in spyder ipython console - \r at start of string , end=""
import time
import sys
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(f"\rnumber{i}",end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Flush is not needed. I tried it without flush and it works just fine.

Comment: This one was it for me with Python 3.11 on Windows 10, in general: `prinf('\r...', end='')`, so carriage return at start of string, not at end. `flush` not needed, as @DonaldDuck already said.

Answer (score 9):

to overwiting the previous line in python all wath you need is to add **end='\r'** to the print function, test this example:

```
import time
for j in range(1,5):
   print('waiting : '+j, end='\r')
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: working perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 8):

I found that for a simple print statement in python 2.7, just put a comma at the end after your `'\r'`.

```
print os.path.getsize(file_name)/1024, 'KB / ', size, 'KB downloaded!\r',
```

This is shorter than other non-python 3 solutions, but also more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Python 2.7.10, and it isn't printing anything. Maybe, you can compile it online and send us a link to see how it is working... ?

Comment: This answer also needs `sys.stdout.flush()` to make sure the output is updated on screen

Answer (score 5):

You can just add '\r' at the end of the string plus a comma at the end of print function. For example:

```
print(os.path.getsize(file_name)/1024+'KB / '+size+' KB downloaded!\r'),
```

Comment: This is for python 3? If so what with default `end` parameter set to `\n`
so u print `(...)KB downloaded!\r\n`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Using `end = '\r'` instead fixes the problem in Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.9

```
for j in range(1,5):
    print('\rwaiting : '+str(j), end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Bouke Versteegh for their answer which gives a great starting point. However I found issues with it where `sys.stdout` wasn't flushed as it should be, and reprinted text moved down the screen repeatedly.

My solution here is an elaboration on that answer, reimplemented to fix those issues and with a `__call__` method for more convenient reprint invocation.

Tested & working on Python 3.8

```
import re, sys

class Reprinter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.text = ''

    def write(self, text):
        """Writes text to stdout."""
        sys.stdout.write(text)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def cursor_prev_line(self):
        """Moves cursor up a line."""
        self.write("\x1b[A")

    def cursor_prev_line_start(self):
        """Moves cursor to start of previous line."""
        self.write("\x1b[F")

    def cursor_line_start(self):
        """Moves cursor to start of current line."""
        self.write("\r")

    def cursor_text_start(self):
        """Moves cursor to start of current text."""
        num_newlines = self.text.count("\n")
        if not num_newlines:
            return self.cursor_line_start()
        for _ in range(num_newlines+1):
            self.cursor_prev_line_start()

    def erase(self):
        """Erases current text by replacing non-whitespace chars with spaces."""
        self.cursor_text_start()
        self.write(re.sub(r"[^\s]", " ", self.text))
        self.cursor_text_start()

    def __call__(self, text):
        """Prints `text` & overwrites all existing text."""
        self.erase()
        self.write(text)
        self.text = text

reprint = Reprinter()
reprint("How now\nbrown cow")
reprint("The rain\nin Spain")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2.7:**

```
print os.path.getsize(file_name)/1024, 'KB / ', size, 'KB downloaded!\r',
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The flush is required if you are printing frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I could find for IPythonConsole is to stay in the same line and clear the whole print output using ANSI codes **(This to avoid an overlapping when the new string is smaller than the previous one)**:

```
def clear_line():
    LINE_CLEAR = '\x1b[2K'
    print(LINE_CLEAR, end= '\r')
```

Example:

```
print('Hello World', end = '\r')
clear_line()
print('Earth', end = '\r')
```

Output:

```
Earth
```

Answer (score -2):

This is my asnwer. I have search for that too. I got many solution but this works for me.

```
 from time import sleep
 for _ in range(5):
     sleep(1)
     print(f'\rWritting on same line with chaning number {_}.',end='')
 else:
     print()
```

- Yes you can use `else:` statement with `for` block. That will add new line when `for` loop finish.
- This will only work with loops. It will not affect other `print()` statements.