# how to edit console output in python

Tags: python, console-application

I'm looking for a way to edit the existing content of the console output.
I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python) which is basically what i want, but i was hoping for something a little bit more sophisticated. Does anyone know of a module or anything else that enables editing the console buffer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this library called [urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) and look at [example applications](http://excess.org/urwid/examples.html) built using that.