# Is there equivalent functionality for 'echo -en ...' in python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace console output in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python)

I am trying to write a program that outputs information including updates to the command line. What I mean by updates is, for example, if files are being processed by the program, perhaps it will keep an updated count of the files processed so far. So `1 file` is replaced with `2 files` and then with `3 files` and so forth.

The following is a sample piece of code that counts out some files and then displays a [loading bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script):

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in {1..10}
do
    echo -ne " $a files processed.\r"
    sleep 1
done
echo ""
echo -ne '#####                     (33%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '#############             (66%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '#######################   (100%)\r'
echo -ne '\n'
```

Basically, the command line output gets periodically overwritten giving the effect of a primitive text-based animation in the terminal.

There are two problems here:

1. From what I know from doctors, the `echo` command is not portable at all.
2. I want to do this in a python program, not with a bash file.

Is there a way to achieve functionality similar to this using python?

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent implementation in Python would be this:

```
import sys, time

for a in range(1,11):
    sys.stdout.write('\r {0} files processed.'.format(a))
    time.sleep(1)

print('')
sys.stdout.write('\r#####                     (33%)')
time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write('\r#############             (66%)')
time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write('\r#######################   (100%)')
print('')
```

You need to use `sys.stdout.write` as `print` by default adds a new-line. If you are using the print-function (Python 3, or by explicitely importing it in Python 2), you can also use `print('text', end='')`. Alternatively in Python 2, you can use the print-statement’s feature to suppress the line termination like this: `print 'text',`

Comment: Or you can do `print "x",` for no new line

Comment: In python2.x, you can also suppress the newline by `print "string",` (note the trailing comma)

Comment: What is it about the `\r` that causes the text to display this way?

Comment: @Eric My code is compatible for both Python 2 and 3 though. But I’m going to add that note for Python 2.

Comment: @Treebranch -- '\r' is "carriage return" -- which means "go back to the beginning of the line" in most terminals/shells.

Comment: @Treebranch The `\r` is a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) that basically tells the console to return to the first character without advancing to the next line. So whatever you print afterwards will overwrite whatever was written in the line before.

Comment: @poke: You shouldn't drop the print statement entirely for compatibility with 2 and 3. That's just silly.

Comment: @Eric There is no print statement in Python 3.

Comment: @poke: And there's no print function in python2. That doesn't mean you should aim to write code that never uses either.

Comment: @Eric Unless a question is exclusively about either Py2 or Py3, I’ll try to only post code that works on both. And I think my explanation after the code is clear enough that you can write it differently too.

Comment: @poke: You've failed to write code that works on both anyway: `print()` prints a literal `()` on python 2.

Comment: @mgilson That will suppress the newline, but any following `print` still has the side-effect of having an unwanted ` ` though..

Comment: Does this code actually work using `sys.stdout.write` (I admit I haven't checked it)... If sys.stdout is buffered, then this might have  the effect of never printing anything.

Comment: @Eric You’re right, missed that in my test; fixed.

Comment: @JonClements In case the console buffers too much, you can add a `sys.stdout.flush()` after each write. Note that you would have to do this even if you used print without a line ending. So using print won’t save you from importing `sys` and accessing the output at a lower lever if that’s everyone’s problem.

Comment: @poke I'm not saying it's a problem - just that it's something the OP may need to be aware of if using this answer

Comment: It's a good idea to add `sys.stdout.flush()` after the write. Otherwise, when writing to line-buffered devices, such as a TTY, the text can remain in a stdio buffer indefinitely. (`echo` doesn't have this problem because it exits immediately after printing, which automatically flushes its stdio buffers.)