# update printed data debug python

Tags: python, printing, display

I have a python program which has some variables that change over time. I want to print them to the screen, without printing in new line. For example:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    v1 = i
    v2 = i+1
    v3 = i+2
```

and while the program is running I want that the display will show:

```
variable 1 value = v1  #v1 changes over time
variable 2 value = v2  #v2 changes over time
variable 3 value = v3  #v3 changes over time
```

by overwriting the previous printed values of v1 v2 and v3

can it be done? I know it can be done with one printed line using `'/r',`, however this time I want to print more lines...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace console output in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clear terminal in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following (but this may not work in all displays), based on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python):

```
import os
for i in range(1,10):
    # First clear the screen
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print('variable 1 value = %s' % i)
    print('variable 2 value = %s' % i+1)        
    print('variable 3 value = %s' % i+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print values in one line, you may:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print 'v1 = {0}, v2 = {0}, v3 = {0}'.format(i, i + 1, i + 2)
```

This link should explainsomething.
[Python Input Output](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: try: print ('v1 = {0}, v2 = {1}, v3 = {2}'.format(i, i + 1, i + 2))