# How to edit console output

Tags: python, console

I have the following very simple code

```
stdout.write("Hello World")
stdout.write("\rBye world")
stdout.write("\rActually hello back")
```

Which prints as expected 'Actually hello back' however if i were to add a newline

```
stdout.write("\n")
```

How can I go back a newline and then to the beginning of the line so I can actually just output "Hi" instead of

```
Actually hello back
Hi
```

I tried

```
stdout.write("\r")
stdout.write("\b")
```

However none of them seem to do the trick. The end goal is to display a big chunk of text and then update the output in real time without having to write again. How can I achieve this in python?

**EDIT**
My question is different than the one suggested as I don't want to modify a single line. I want to be able to print 4-5 lines of text and then replace them in real time instead of just one line that is modified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace console output in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python)

Comment: @TonyBabarino Check edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if You want to gain full control over the terminal, I would suggest to use the [curses library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html).

> The curses module provides an interface to the curses library, the
>   de-facto standard for portable advanced terminal handling.

Using it, You can edit multiple lines in terminal like this:

```
import curses
import time

stdscr = curses.initscr()

stdscr.addstr("line 1\n")
stdscr.addstr("line 2\n")
stdscr.refresh()
time.sleep(3)

stdscr.erase()
stdscr.addstr("edited line 1\n")
stdscr.addstr("edited line 2\n")
stdscr.refresh()
time.sleep(3)

curses.endwin()
```

The capabilities of this library are much greater though. Full tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html).