# How to write to specific character cell in terminal without libraries?

Tags: python, terminal

Is it possible to write to a specific character cell in a terminal in Python 3 without the help of a library? If not, what library would be best for this purpose?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264588/python-control-output-positions-in-terminal-console

Comment: I'm asking for a without-library solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the curses module. If you *really* don't want to, you can write codes to your terminal. All codes are here.

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes

You can send them using `sys.stdout.write()`:

```
sys.stdout.write("\033[10;16H#")
```

Comment: The idea was I _really_ don't want to. Thank you!