# Make a pinned print to the terminal with python?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, terminal

How can I print to the terminal messages that will be
 pinned to the top or bottom on the terminal console?

Thanks !

Comment: Please show some effort in resolving this task yourself before asking us. We're not a coding service.

Comment: Trust me I searched before I asked
Since I couldn't find it, I decided to ask here

Comment: That's good, but it doesn't show at all in the question, so how would we know? We might recommend solutions you've already tried, so if possible include things you've tried and show us the effort so we better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [curses module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) to make a pinned message I found this solution in an already asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264588/python-control-output-positions-in-terminal-console) I believe you can add your string in the window.addstr function

```
import time
import curses

def pbar(window):
    height, width = window.getmaxyx()
    for i in range(10):
        window.addstr(height -1, 0, "[" + ("=" * i) + ">" + (" " * (10 - i )) + "]")
        window.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.5)

curses.wrapper(pbar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the terminal size you are running your code with help of the `os` module:

```
import os

def ptb(top_text, bottom_text):
    ts = os.get_terminal_size()
    n = ts.lines()
    os.system('clear') # Linux terminal only
    print(top_text + '\n'*(n-2) + bottom_text)
```