# Replacing Multiple lines of Console Text Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i am creating a slot machine as a little project for fun and learning, I was wondering if there was a way to replace multiple lines of text in the console. I have it replacing one line but I would like to be able to print three lines then the top be replaced with the middle then middle with the bottom and continue untill the loop is finished. I am still a beginner so if there are any tips you have for me and or please feel free to critique my code. Thank you

```
import sys
import time
from random import randint

slot_possibilities = ["  Star ","  Moon ","  Sun! "," Monkey"]
wait_time = 15

print "--------------------------------"
print "|--------Monkey-----Slots------|"
print "|------------------------------|"
while wait_time != 0 :
    x = randint(0,3)
    y = randint(0,3)
    z = randint(0,3)
    sys.stdout.write("\r|" + slot_possibilities[x] + " || " + slot_possibilities[y] + " || "+ slot_possibilities[z] + " |")
    time.sleep(1)
    wait_time -= 1
print
print
```

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python) answer tells you how to do what you want

Comment: @scotty3785 Im not really sure if that helps. I can already replace a single line of text my code already does that and thats what that answer is doing am i wrong?

Comment: You are going to need `curses` for this, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html
There are many examples about using on the internet which should help you get started using curses, which is very powerful and useful once you know it.

Comment: @Dartmouth wow that is cool thank you so much. Started working on it and man is this difficult but thats why I am doing this. Time To Learn Thanks