# How can I apply backspace symbols in vim?

Tags: vim

In my script, I print backspace symbols in order to implement some UI in console as it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6169274/3084258).

It works well, but now I want to save the output to my log file (via redirecting stdout). When I read this file using command-line tools such as `tail` or `less` I get the *final* 'output view' of my script (i.e. the completed progress bar in this case) and this behavior is preferred for me. But if I open the log file with vim it shows *all* written symbols to the file with just escaping backslashes as `^H`.

How can I set my vim to display my log file similarly to `less` or `tail` here?

---

Here's an example.

1) The python script:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    if i: sys.stdout.write(chr(8) * 10)
    sys.stdout.write(str(i) * 10)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
sys.stdout.write('\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

2) Running the script: `python program.py > out.txt`

3) The output of the `cat out.txt`:

```
$ cat out.txt 
9999999999
```

4) Displayed content of my `vim out.txt`:

```
0000000000^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H1111111111^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H2222222222^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H3333333333^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H4444444444^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H5555555555^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H6666666666^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H7777777777^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H8888888888^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H9999999999
```

Comment: Adding sample text and maybe screenshots should help.

Comment: Are you saying that vim displays a literal `\r` and you'd like it to interpret that as a newline?

Comment: @romainl,  i've added an example

Comment: @jeremysprofile, I want the content in 4) to be like in 4) in my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following command to replace the special key `^H` (see `:help i_BS`) with backspaces:

```
:g/\b/while getline('.') =~ '[^\b]\b' | s/[^\b]\b//g | endwhile
```

Sample input:

```
0000000000^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H1111111111^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H2222222222^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H3333333333^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H4444444444^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H5555555555^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H6666666666^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H7777777777^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H8888888888^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H9999999999
```

Output:

```
9999999999
```

Comment: Can I set up my vim to do it automatically on a startup? Cuz I don't want to type this replacement each time I open my log file

Comment: Sure, you could add an auto command to your .vimrc. For example, `autocmd BufEnter filename silent! cmd`. Here `cmd` is the command provided in the answer.  `filename` can be a search patter, for example `*.log` will apply the auto command to every `.log` file.

Comment: yep, i've set it up. But one more issue: vim treats this substitution as modifying the content and thus even if I opened it only for reading (as logs normally opened to) vim asks me to quit via `:q!`. Is there a solution to the problem that avoids this, i.e. that changed only the _view_ of the content in vim, not the content itself?

Comment: Then you could use: `autocmd BufEnter filename set readonly | cabbrev q q! | silent! cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the backspaces, and see the result in vim:

```
cat out.txt | col -b | vim -
```

Comment: Can I set up my vim to do it automatically on a startup? Or I can't and need to do this piping each time I want to open such a log file?

Answer (score 0):

This command:

```
$ file out.txt
```

shows:

```
out.txt: ASCII text, with overstriking
```

This command:

```
$ cat -v out.txt
```

shows (hard-wrapping added for readability):

```
0000000000^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H1111111111^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H
2222222222^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H3333333333^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H
4444444444^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H5555555555^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H
6666666666^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H7777777777^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H
8888888888^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H9999999999
```

And this command:

```
$ xxd out.txt
```

shows:

```
00000000: 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 0808 0808 0808  0000000000......
00000010: 0808 0808 3131 3131 3131 3131 3131 0808  ....1111111111..
00000020: 0808 0808 0808 0808 3232 3232 3232 3232  ........22222222
00000030: 3232 0808 0808 0808 0808 0808 3333 3333  22..........3333
00000040: 3333 3333 3333 0808 0808 0808 0808 0808  333333..........
00000050: 3434 3434 3434 3434 3434 0808 0808 0808  4444444444......
00000060: 0808 0808 3535 3535 3535 3535 3535 0808  ....5555555555..
00000070: 0808 0808 0808 0808 3636 3636 3636 3636  ........66666666
00000080: 3636 0808 0808 0808 0808 0808 3737 3737  66..........7777
00000090: 3737 3737 3737 0808 0808 0808 0808 0808  777777..........
000000a0: 3838 3838 3838 3838 3838 0808 0808 0808  8888888888......
000000b0: 0808 0808 3939 3939 3939 3939 3939 0a    ....9999999999.
```

So… the backspaces (`^H`) *and the previous strings* are all in fact part of the file and Vim, being a plain text editor, shows its actual content.

As expected.

Comment: Of course I know that previous strings are all part of the file (how could vim know about them otherwise?) and thus my question is how to force vim to _apply_ backspaces automatically on opening