# How to print the progress of a task at somewhere fixed in python3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run a time time-consuming 'for' loop, and want to print the process in the fixed place of the console and refresh each loop

I try print function like this

```py
for i in range(total):
    ...some code....
    print('---%.2f---'%(float(i)/total), sep='')
```

It seems does't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text Progress Bar in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

I use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6169274/10041823) to display progress bar:

The methods used:

```
def startProgress(title):
    global progress_x
    sys.stdout.write(title + ": [" + "-"*50 + "]" + chr(8)*51)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    progress_x = 0


def progress(x):
    global progress_x
    x = int(x * 50 // 100)
    sys.stdout.write("#" * (x - progress_x))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    progress_x = x


def endProgress():
    sys.stdout.write("#" * (50 - progress_x) + "]\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

An example of use:

```
import time
import sys

startProgress("Test")
for i in range(500):
    progress(i * 100 / 500)
    time.sleep(.1)
endProgress()
```

The progress will look like this with the `#` moving at the same time of the progress:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that this code doesn't work well, I can only see '#' in the progress bar without  '-'

Comment: Have you the same as the picture ?