# Python3 how to clear previous prints while looping, flush?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, flush

I want to show only one item at the screen I guess this should be done with print(..., flush=True) but it don't work as I expected.

```
for i in range(0,100):
    print(i, end='', flush=True)
```

Now I get a numbers like this `012345678....` and what I want to see at the screen is only one number without seeing previous prints so with first iteration it shows only `0` second shows only `1`, I thought flush would do the trick but it didn't so where am I wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace console output in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python)

Comment: Yes and no it does what I wanted but why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `end='\r'` as an argument to `print()`. `\r` escape sequence moves the cursor to the starting of the line. `flush` is not the correct argument for doing this.

Your code can be:

```py
for i in range(0,100):
    print(i, end='\r')
```

Comment: May I ask why flush isn't correct argument?

Comment: And if you don't mind what if I have string that is getting smaller? How would I this?

Comment: @StrudzonyWedrowiec Then add spaces to the string

Comment: Ok I get it now, thank you, very much

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `os` module to do the same

```
import os
import time

for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("clear") # For Linux
    #os.system("cls") # For Windows
```

I have used `time.sleep()` to make sure the effect is visible otherwise it executes very fast. You may make variations as per the need.

Comment: I was aware of that but I was looking for solution similar as bluefish and Sumagna Das posted