# Python delete print

Tags: python, printing

If I for example had a code like this:

```
score = 0
loop = true
while loop:
    score = (score) + 1
    print(score)
```

But I wanted to only print the new value of score instead of a long list of previous values aswell how would I do that?

Comment: Don't put it in the loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace console output in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python) Of course, if the ultimate purpose  is to produce progress bar, there are convenient packages to display progress bar

Comment: Note that `loop = true` is invalid (`true` is undefined name). And braces are redundant in `score = (score) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Something", end='\r')
```

This way, any successive output will overwrite this one.

```
score = 0
while True:
    score += 1
    print(f"{score}  ", end='\r')
```

---

Notice that in Python `true` is undefined, and unlike `C`, `C++`, `JavaScript` and some other languages, `True` and `False` are uppercase.