# is there a way to change 1 to 2 to 3 etc with python

Tags: python

How (in python) can  I change numbers to be going up. For example, 1 (time.sleep(0.05)) then it changes to two, and so on. But there will be text already above it, so you can't use a simple `os.system('clear')`

So like this:

> print("how much money do you want to make?")<
> 'number going up without deleting the "how much money" part'

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is really unclear...

Comment: `print('\b2', end='')`?

Comment: this question is a bit unclear, maybe u can improve it with some detail or more examples?

Comment: Maybe this might help?: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: try this : print(i, end='\r')

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.3)
    sys.stdout.write("\rDoing thing %i" % i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Edit: This was taken from [Replace console output in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want it to sleep for 1 second the first time, 2 seconds for the second time, and so on. You could create a function.

```
counter = 0
def my_function():
  global counter
  sleep(counter)
  counter = counter + 1
for i in range(3):
     my_function()
```

This is an example of what you can do.Change it to meet your needs.

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear, but maybe you mean the following:

```py
import time
for item in [0.05,2,3]:
    time.sleep(item)
```

and

```py
number = 3
print("how much money do you want to make? {}".format(number))
```