# How can I create a callable progress bar with a real-time clock in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to monitor a process that takes a bunch of time. My code goes through a number of files, operating on them a couple of times. The files are big, and I want to know how much time has elapsed.

I borrowed [a progress bar that I found in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37630397/6338996). After that, I tried creating a thread using threading. This is my attempt:

```
def progress_bar(current, total, filename='', bar_length = 20):
    threading.Timer(1., progress_bar(current,total,filename)).start()
    
    percent = float(current) * 100 / total
    arrow   = '-' * int(percent/100 * bar_length - 1) + '>'
    spaces  = ' ' * (bar_length - len(arrow))

    # sys.stdout.write(f'\rProgress: [{arrow}{spaces}] {percent:.0f}% (converting {filename})')
    # sys.stdout.flush()    
    
    time_passed = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.gmtime(time.monotonic()-start))
    
    if current==total: 
        print("\rProgress: [------------------->] 100% (COMPLETED)\033[K | "\
              f"time passed: {time_passed}")
    else:
        print(f"\rProgress: [{arrow}{spaces}] {percent:.2f}% | "\
              f"tile: {filename} | "\
              f"time passed: {time_passed}",
              end='\r',flush=True)
```

I include the full code snippet so I don't erase something that may have been important. As you can see, the function itself has arguments that need to be passed (to itself, I presume), as opposed to the simple examples I've seen where there are no arguments to be passed.

I would want for the function to be called both when the code progresses and when a second passes. How could I achieve that?

Comment: `start` variable is undefined in your code

Comment: start is defined elsewhere globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed using already existing libs like `tqdm` would be the best in your case.

That said, if you absolutely want to code the threaded version yourself (good way to practise threading...), you can do like so :

```py
from threading import Thread
import time

def process(status):
    # Replace by a walk though your paths...
    for filename in files_to_process:
        status["current"] += 1
        status["filename"] = filename
        time.sleep(0.005)

def progress_bar(current, total, filename='', timer=0, bar_length=20):
    percent = float(current) * 100 / total
    arrow   = '-' * int(percent/100 * bar_length - 1) + '>'
    spaces  = ' ' * (bar_length - len(arrow))

    time_passed = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.gmtime(timer))

    if current==total:
        print("\rProgress: [------------------->] 100% (COMPLETED)\033[K | "\
              f"time passed: {time_passed}")
        return False
    else:
        print(f"\rProgress: [{arrow}{spaces}] {percent:.2f}% | "\
              f"tile: {filename} | "\
              f"time passed: {time_passed}",
              end='\r', flush=True)
        return True

# Define work
work_status = {
    "total":1000,
    "current":0,
    "filename":""
}
files_to_process = ["file_"+str(i).zfill(4) for i in range(work_status["total"])]

# Launch process in a thread
thread = Thread(target=process, args=[work_status])
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
start = time.time()

# Check status every 100ms and show progress
while progress_bar(work_status["current"], work_status["total"], work_status["filename"], time.time()-start):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

A few comments on the code above :

- `thread.setDaemon(True)` is advised if you want to make sure the thread is killed when the program exits
- sending `work_status` variable to the thread as param, is not necessary here since it's global in the scope. But still you should do it to make sure it works even if the var is non global (if the thread is defined in another scope...)
- Of course the while loop needs to be secured to avoid eternity...

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted! (to learn how to thread). Thank you! With your answer, I will be able to keep working and learning. | A couple of notes for future people: Keyboard Interrupt stops the main thread, but the progress bar keeps updating infinitely; also, it seems ```thread.setDaemon(True)``` is deprecated and should be called as ```thread.daemon = True```.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) which shows you progress at all times. The snipplet to go over all files in the current directory would look like this:

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
path = '.'
for filename in tqdm(next(os.walk(path))[2]):
    process_file(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using fastprogress:

```
pip install fastprogress
```

**Sample Code:**

```
from fastprogress import progress_bar
import time

def long_running_task():
    for i in progress_bar(range(1, 101), display=1):
        # Update the progress bar every second
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    long_running_task()
```

**Output:**

[image]