# Same-line output overwriting previous content does not work (python 2.7)

Tags: python, linux, printing, python-2.7

Following the description given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output-python-2-5) how to create output in python in such a way, that the previous output is overwritten, I tried the following code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

for val in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(val, end='\r')
```

but do not see any output at all. With `end=\n` it works as expected (i.e. the numbers 0 to 9 in a vertical column). What is the reason I do not see any output? Do I need to flush something? Is this operating-system depended (working on Ubuntu Linux)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the stream isn't flushed until it gets a '\n'.

Have a look at this article: [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/1045800)

Try if it works when you start Python with -u.

Comment: It works either with `python -u` as well as adding a `sys.atdout.flush()` in the code after the print statement.