# How to alter a string after it has been printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, I ask this question on behalf of someone else but I would also like to know if and how it is possible.

Let's say you have a given line of code producing the string

> Time left: 4

Is there any way how I can then after this string has been printed edit the value of the "4" and change it to a "3" and then reprint the new string on the same line so Time left: 4 is replaced with Time left: 3 without causing a new line to be printed.

I hope you understand the question I did my best to explain it.

Comment: It'll be worth starting by looking at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.2

Comment: And here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output-python-2-5 (there's a python3 solution)

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo ahh - that's the one I was trying to find... only progress bar sprang to mind though :)

Comment: @Kieran: I would like to ask that you modify the question to 'How to alter a string after it has been *displayed*'.  After a string has been *printed*, a small bottle of paint is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Print a carriage return (`\r`), and make sure that your `print` statement is not writing a newline by adding `end=''` to the print arguments.  After each print, make sure you flush stdout using `sys.stdout.flush()`.  For example:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(4, 0, -1):
    print('\rTime left:', i, end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

On Python 2.x where `print` is a statement instead of a function, just add a trailing comma to prevent the newline:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(4, 0, -1):
    print '\rTime left:', i,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That will print only `Time left: 1`.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo Oops, forgot about needing to flush stdout, thanks.

Comment: This seems to print Time left: for each value of i

Comment: The carriage return moves the print position to the beginning of the line, so when "Time left:" is printed again it just overwrites the same characters in the same location.

Answer (score 2):

One method is printing the backspace escape character (`\b`), which will will move the text cursor one character back; however, it is your responsibility to print something *afterward* to replace the text.

For example, if the current text in the terminal is `Time left: 4` and you print `"\b"`, the user will see nothing has changed.  However, if you print `"\b5"`, it will replace it with 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
3>> for i in range(5, 0, -1):
...   print('\rTime left: {}      '.format(i), end='', flush=True)
...   time.sleep(1)
... 
Time left: 1
```

(note: the output will actually be changing on your system :P )