# Keeping the user's input intact when outputing to terminal at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, output

To simplify, let's say I'm trying to write a command line two-way chat in Python. I would like the user to input his message with `input()` at the command prompt, but a listening thread could print a message at any moment. By default, this would "break" the user's input. Visually something like this:

```
userB>Stop interuserA wrote:Hey check this out!
rupting me!
```

The closest I was able to find was [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304078/how-to-print-over-raw-inputs-line-in-python) which is almost, but not exactly, what I'm looking for, but it did point me towards the `blessings` package which seems to be what I need (although I'm happy with an answer for any package, or even pure ANSII).

What I'm trying to achieve is to print incoming output from a Thread *above* the user's input, so that his text doesn't break. Let's say the user is typing:

```
userB>Stop inter
```

Suddenly a message comes in from the thread, but our user's input doesn't brake:

```
userA says: Ok I won't interrupt you
userB>Stop inter
```

What should my threads theoretical `print_incoming_message()` method look like to achieve this?

NB: I'm using Linux and am not interested in cross-platform compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.

One is to use `ncurses`. There are python bindings for this. With `ncurses`, the terminal screen is under your complete control, and you can print characters at any point.

Without `ncurses`, you can't write above the current line. What you *can* do, however, is print a `\r` character and go back to the beginning of the line.

If you save the user's input (say he wrote `foo`), and you want to print the line `bar` above that, you can output:

```
\rbar\nfoo
```

This will overwrite the current line, and introduce a newline, moving the user's input down. The effect is similar, but it won't be as tamper-proof as `ncurses`.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to keep track of the user input myself or is there a way to say "save current input" before overwriting? ie: is there a way to get input that hasn't been flushed yet?

Comment: You should track input yourself, from the last newline entered

Comment: Discovered the `readline` module that has a `get_line_buffer()` method. It's working pretty good so far! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#module-readline