# How can I remove last printed line in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, countdown

I'm trying to make countdown program with python. I want to turn that into it removes last printed line, so i can print new second.

```
import time

def countdown():
    minute = 60
    while minute >= 0:
        m, s = divmod(minute, 60)
        time_left = str(m).zfill(2) + ':' + str(s).zfill(2)
        print(time_left)
        time.sleep(1) 
        minute -= 1

countdown()
```

I am running python 2.7.13 on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [output to the same line overwriting previous output ? python (2.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output-python-2-5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (it's made in python2):

```
import time, sys

def countdown(totalTime):
    try:
        while totalTime >= 0:
            mins, secs = divmod(totalTime, 60)
            sys.stdout.write("\rWaiting for {:02d}:{:02d}  minutes...".format(mins, secs))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
            totalTime -= 1
            if totalTime <= -1:
                print "\n"
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit("\n^C Detected!\nExiting...")
```

Call it like this:
countdown(*time*)
For example: countdown(600) for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You could write directly to `stdout`, instead of using print.  And the `\r` character will go to the beginning of the line, not the next line.

```
 import time
 import sys

 def countdown():
     minute = 60
     while minute >= 0:
         m, s = divmod(minute, 60)
         time_left = str(m).zfill(2) + ':' + str(s).zfill(2)
         sys.stdout.write("%s\r" % time_left)
         sys.stdout.flush()
         time.sleep(1) 
         minute -= 1
```