# Python: How to make a infinite loop that will keep counting up until a certain number is reached

Tags: python-3.x

How would you make a loop that would keep counting up until lets say 60. And also how could you display it and then update the number on the same line?

Comment: A loop that stops counting when a certain number is reached is not "infinite". Try something like `for i in range(60)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update your output in place you simply have to [set the end keyword to a carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436827/7403700) this way the vursdour will be returned to the start and overwrite the existing string.

I made a quick example script (with a timout so that the countdown can be seen

```
import time
count = 0
while True:
    print(count, end='\r')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    if count == 60:
        break
    else:
        count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to print it like:( x:y:count ). Like this. Kinda like a stopwatch?