# Anchor text Python CLI output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Situation: I am trying to write a command line program that prints the following

```
Some text 1
Some text 2

-------------------------------------------------------
Anchored text : Time now is: 12:00
```

I would like to only update `Some text 1` and `Some text 2` constantly, but `Anchored text` will be updated at a different pace compared to the others.

Problem: I cannot find the right search term for what I am looking for.

Question: How do I anchor a line of text in a python command line application?

Comment: You can use the curses library. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output to the same line overwriting previous output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output)

Comment: @Justlearnedit that answers for `some text 1` and `some text 2`. But the main focus is on how to anchor the text at the bottom

Comment: @PramoteKuacharoen is there a native way to achieve this? (I'm assuming no, but hopefully prove me wrong)

Comment: If you want to move around the screen, that is the way.  It is not difficult to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small example may help you.

```
import random
import curses
from datetime import datetime
import time

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)


while True:
    key = w.getch()
    if key == ord('q'):
        curses.endwin()
        quit()

    t = datetime.now()
    date_str = f"Date {t.strftime('%B %d, %Y')}"
    w.addstr(10, 10, date_str)
    time_str = f"Time now is: {t.strftime(' %X')}"
    w.addstr(sh-2, sw-50, time_str)
    time.sleep(1)
```