# How to display "TypeWriter Effect" animation?

Tags: python, text

I have code to make running text:

```
from time import sleep
import os

def run(text):
    for i in text:
        print (i, end="", flush=True)
        sleep(0.07)

teks = " Hello\n"
teks2 = " world"
run(teks)

run(teks2)
```

and output

```
hello
world
```

I want to display the results like in the youtube video [TypeWriter Effect In ReactJS Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eXQJYL1s1k&ab_channel=PedroTech).

Can you help me please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output I think this is the answer for your question

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i didn't find the answer i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does essentially the same thing as what's in the video:

```
from time import sleep
CPS = 3  # Update speed in Characters Per Second.

def run(text, width=60, delay=1/CPS):
    text = text.replace('\n', '')  # Removed any newlines.
    for i in range(len(text)+1):
        print('\r' + text[:i].center(width), end="", flush=True)
        sleep(delay)

    for i in range(len(text)+1, -1, -1):
        print('\r' + text[:i].center(width), end="", flush=True)
        sleep(delay)

run("Hello\n")
run("world")
```

The code above can be streamlined slightly by applying the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle of software development:

```
from itertools import chain
from time import sleep
CPS = 3  # Update speed in Characters Per Second.

def run(text, width=50, delay=1/CPS):
    for line in text.splitlines():
        interval = len(line) + 1
        for i in chain(range(interval), range(interval, -1, -1)):
            print('\r' + line[:i].center(width), end="", flush=True)
            sleep(delay)

run("Hello\nworld")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

EDITED:

```
from time import sleep


def run(word):
    for letter in word:
        print(letter, end="", flush=True)
        sleep(0.5)

    print("\r", end="")

run("Hello")
run("world !")
```

You were calling the function twice with different arguments, so the loop would run twice as well. Next, you had the line-breaking character in your String (I mean "\n"), this will split the lines, so `end=""` had no effect in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the output I want is when the "hello" appears, then it is replaced by "word"

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```py
def run(text):
    for i in text:
        print(i, flush=True, end='')
        sleep(0.07)
    print('\r', end='')
```