# Input timeout with countdown timer in python

Tags: python, input, subprocess, timeout

Anyone has an idea how to do something, like this code would do

```
import subprocess  
subprocess.call('timeout /T 30')
```

The main idea is wait for user input for some specific amount of time and show to user how many seconds left until end.
The problem with the code above is the impossibility of changing displaying text
Cant find a solution for windows ...

Comment: Try using the carriage return character to overwrite the currently displayed text. It can be accessed by '\r'. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this:

```py
import asyncio

async def setInterval(callback, countdown):
    async def job():
        if countdown <= 0:
            print('Countdown finished')
            return

        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        callback(countdown)
        await setInterval(callback, countdown-1)

    await asyncio.ensure_future(job())  

def myCallback(timeLeft):
    print(f'Time left: {timeLeft}')

async def otherTask():
    while True:
        print('some other code running')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        setInterval(myCallback, 10),
        otherTask()
    )

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The code above lets you trigger the function `myCallback` every second, which you could use to display the time left to the users without blocking other code you might want to run while it is counting down.

Sample output is like:

```
some other code running
Time left: 10
some other code running
Time left: 9
Time left: 8
some other code running
Time left: 7
Time left: 6
some other code running
Time left: 5
Time left: 4
some other code running
Time left: 3
Time left: 2
some other code running
Time left: 1
Countdown finished
some other code running
some other code running
some other code running
```