# How do I print over a previous line which took in input? Python

Tags: python, input, printing

So in Python, the user places input on a line in the console and it stays there. I want the code to basically print over the previous input line, covering the user input on the last line with a printed string. Is there any way to do that?

How many planets are in the solar system?

#user inputs answer on this line

--->

How many planets are in the solar system?

correct

Comment: Would clearing the console window also be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to clear the console with os.system('cls') and re-print the question.

### Code:

```
import os
print('How many planets are in the solar system?')
value = int(input())

os.system('cls')
print('How many planets are in the solar system?')
if value == 8:
    print('Good job you are right!')
else:
    print('You are wrong.')
```

### Output:

**Before the clear:**

```
How many planets are in the solar system?
3
```

**After the clear:**

```
How many planets are in the solar system?
You are wrong.
```

This works great and doesn't require much code.

Comment: I should've stated this earlier, but there's already text printed before the input which I still want to stay there, so clearing the entire console doesn't work for my situation. Thank you though Blue Robin!

Comment: Oh @Bebop100 I’ll try and figure something out!

Comment: @Bebop100 I couldn't really find anything. Maybe you can try to reprint all the past output and do this by storing everything in a list?

Comment: That is a possibility, but it seems a little annoying. If that's the best I have though, I'll definitely do that.

Comment: It might be @Bebop100 but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Bebop100 I found this post though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output 
the top answer didn't work for me but it could work