# How to replace a line which is printed?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```py
def ranges(ip):
    try:
        part = ip.split('.')
        a = part[0]
        b = part[1]
        c = part[2]
        d = part[3]
        for c in range(1, 256):
                 for d in range(1, 256):
                     ip_result = (str(a) + '.' + str(b) + '.' + str(c) + '.' + str(d))
                     print(ip_result, end='\r')
                     open('IpRanged.txt','a').write(ip_result+"\n")
    except:
        ...
```

It is supposed to show each output on the same line of the terminal, but it does not properly show every output. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You want to print the generated IP address in a single line which is updated every iteration? Than it works like you have done. You see not every print, because it is so fast, that you can not see all prints... Notes to your code: The `try` is missing an `except`, `part[2]` and `part[3]` are never used.

Comment: Also, your code produces an error as you didn't include an except statement.

Comment: Yes II just did not upload the full code which has except statement and that part[0] and part[1] have some work but not here used

Comment: So is there any way that it can print in one line without buffering

Comment: `print(ip_result, end='\r', flush=True)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print

Comment: You want a fast counting smooth print of your generated IP addresses? Maybe some of these example codes get you the desired result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the linked duplicate. If the output ends with a carriage return (`end='\r'`), then it doesn't end with a newline, causing the problem described there. For future questions, though, please read [ask] and try to **ask a question** - "Please help me" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), and we [don't like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) smilies here as this is **not a discussion forum**. We **do** want complete English sentences with proper punctuation and grammar. I edited the question to lead by example.