# How can I determine when a user is in the process of entering something as an input in Python?

Tags: python, input, chat

For practice and fun, I am working on a small Python chat client which connects to an online service. The chat allows the other users to see when the main user is typing. I'd like the other users to see when the program's user is in the process of entering something to send to them.

```
>>>Stranger: Hello, user.
>>>Hello, how are y...
```

This would perhaps set the variable *hasSomethingEntered* to True because something is being typed whereas

```
>>>Stranger: Hello, user.
>>>
```

would set the variable *hasSomethingEntered* to False because the user has not yet typed anything into the input box. This variable would then be passed into a separate thread which communicates with the server and lets it know that the client's user is typing.

Right now I am using Python's *input* command to get the user's chat entries. Is it possible to do what I wish to do using Python? If not, can you recommend an alternative way or language that I can use to accomplish the same goal?

I hope it is clear what I am trying to accomplish here and thank you in advance.

Comment: You should check out the curses module for python (it doesn't work on windows I think) http://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html

Comment: Thanks. This is really great because it has a lot of what I need. Unfortunately, I am trying to make this client usable on both Windows and unix systems so I need to find some sort of alternative that will work on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read one character at a time, making *hasSomethingEntered* true after the first character and false after the end of a line.  Unfortunately, this is platform-dependent.

Windows:

```
import msvcrt
one_character= msvcrt.getch()
```

Unix:

```
import sys, tty
tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
one_character= sys.stdin.read(1)
```

In the later case you will most probably want to save and restore `sys.stdin`'s mode with

```
import sys, termios
previous_mode= termios.tcgetattr( sys.stdin.fileno() )
```

and

```
import sys, termios
termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin.fileno(),termios.TCSADRAIN, previous_mode )
```

, respectively.

Comment: I like the idea to process the entry one character at a time instead of looking at the string as a whole. I was able to accomplish what I needed using this as well as some information about dynamic printing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122385/dynamic-terminal-printing-with-python