# display "updating text" on console

Tags: python, bash, console

Is there a way to create things like progress bars or updating percentages to the command line in python? It would be much preferred to a new line for every update.

something that looks like this
[image]

```
for n in range(10):
    print n*10,'%'
```

Comment: A simple search on SO reveals a lot of possibilities: [Dynamic terminal printing with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122385/dynamic-terminal-printing-with-python), [output to the same line overwriting previous output ? python (2.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output-python-2-5), etc

Comment: Look at [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vladignatyev/06860ec2040cb497f0f3

Comment: Thanks. "Updating text" hadn't yielded anything. Hopefully this will help others who describe this that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing the `\r` character (carriage return) will move the cursor to the beginning of the line then you can re-write it from there. You will also need to keep the `print` function from adding a line break by providing `end=''` as a parameter.

To clarify how to use it, the example below increments a progress counter every second, re-writing the line every second:

```py
import time

a = 0
while 1:
  text = "progress: " + str(a) + "%"
  print ("\r" + text + "        ", end='')
  time.sleep (1)
  a = a + 1
```

You will need this little amount of empty spaces at the end of the string (after `text` in the example). When you print variable-length text (like filenames or paths) you may have a situation where the next line update will be shorter than the previous, and you will need to clean up the excess characters from the previous iteration.