# Display a bar in the shell to visually indicate a constantly changing tally

Tags: python

I would like to write a simple, command-line based, monitoring tool in Python that displays, on the command line, a visual indicator of a tally. The tally in question is the tally of messages on a queue but that’s not really important, what’s important is I want to display a visual indicator of a tally that can increase or decrease. I *do* know what the maximum possible value will be.

Does anyone know of an easy way of achieving this in Python?

In my head I’m envisaging a horizontal bar in the shell that shrinks and grows according to the tally. Note I don’t want a progress bar (I know I could use [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) to give me progress bars)  because this is an unbounded tally, there is no notion of it ending.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Found some solutions here that look like they might work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516916/display-updating-text-on-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take care not to end the line with `\n`, you can print backspace characters (`\b`) to move the "cursor" back to the beginning of the line, and overwrite the bar you just printed.

Simple example:

```py
import sys
import random
import time

BAR_WIDTH = 50
curr_bar_width = 0

while True:
    tally = random.randint(0, 50)
    bar = '#' * tally + '.' * (BAR_WIDTH - tally)
    print('\b' * curr_bar_width + bar, file=sys.stderr, end='', flush=True)
    curr_bar_width = len(bar)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```