# Python Capitalize And Uncapitalize Animation

Tags: python, animation, jquery-animate, sys, pythonista

I am looking to do a type of text animation using python.
If you have used Metasploit, during the loading a wave of text appears
Example:
First
fIrst
fiRst
FirSt
firsT
(all of it will be on the same line)
I was thinking of something using sys.stdout.write("") but I cant replace
the last symbol I place down with a lowercase after it was Capitalized.

```
# This version is fixed and works
import sys, time
lowerstr = "buffering"
upperstr = lowerstr.upper()
for x in range(len(lowerstr)):
     s = '\r' + lowerstr[0:x] + upperstr[x] + lowerstr[x+1:] + '\r'
     sys.stdout.write(s)
     sys.stdout.flush()
     time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: This seems to be around what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122385/dynamic-terminal-printing-with-python

Comment: I modded it the script below and added "\r" to the begging and fixed it so it could do what I wanted, thank you guys for the help!      s = '\r' + lowerstr[0:x] + upperstr[x] + lowerstr[x+1:] + '\r'

Comment: newer change question! append modifications at the end. Now nobody will know what was oryginal code and oryginal problem in code.

Comment: The original script wasn't close at all to the functionality of the proper script. It was more or less a far concept. But I understand your concern. :D *original* And I won't delete scripts if they had an error.

Comment: If an answer helped you, mark it as accepted. I'm sure the answer author would appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import time

data = ["b","u","f","f","e","r","i","n","g"]

# display with one upper char

for x in range(len(data)):
    # remeber lower char
    old = data[x]

    # replace with upper char
    data[x] = old.upper()

    # create full text
    text = "".join(data)

    # display full text
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()

    # put back lower char
    data[x] = old

    time.sleep(1)

# display without upper chars at the end 

text = "".join(data)

sys.stdout.write("\r")
sys.stdout.write(text)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

If you put extra char at then end in `data` which doesn't have upper version - ie. empty string `""` - then you don't need code after `for` loop.

You can put also empty string at start to display first text without upper chars.

```
import sys
import time

# text with extra chars at the start and at the end
data = ["", "b","u","f","f","e","r","i","n","g", ""]

# display with one upper char

for x in range(len(data)):
    # remeber lower char
    old = data[x]

    # replace with upper char
    data[x] = old.upper()

    # create full text
    text = "".join(data)

    # display full text
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()

    # put back lower char
    data[x] = old

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This version combines the strings rather than just iterating over each character. You could do away with `upperstr` altogether by using `.upper()` on the appropriate character. Note that you should not use `list` as a variable name since it is a Python builtin.

```
import sys
import time

lowerstr = "buffering"
upperstr = lowerstr.upper()
for x in range (len(lowerstr)):
    s = lowerstr[0:x] + upperstr[x] + lowerstr[x+1:] + '\r'
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this animation using ios pythonista scene

```
import scene

label_text = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def custom_action(node, progress):
    ntext = node.text
    i = int(len(ntext)*progress)
    iminus1txt = ntext[i-1].lower() if i > 0 else ''
    ithtxt = ntext[i].capitalize() if i < len(ntext) else ''
    if i > 0:
        before_i = ntext[:(i-1)]
    else:
        before_i = ''
    if i < len(ntext):
        node.text = before_i+iminus1txt+ithtxt+ntext[(i+1):]
    else:
        node.text = label_text

class TextCapitalAnimate(scene.Scene):
    def setup(self):
        center = self.bounds.center()
        labelnode = scene.LabelNode(label_text, font=('Courier', 20),
                                position=center, parent=self)
        A = scene.Action
        animate_action = A.repeat(A.call(custom_action, 2), 0)
        labelnode.run_action(animate_action)

scene.run(TextCapitalAnimate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import sys

string = input(str('Enter text : '))
list = []
for x in string:
 list.append(x)

while True:
 for x in range(len(list)):
  old = list[x]
  list[x] = old.upper()
  final = "".join(list)
  sys.stdout.write('\r')
  sys.stdout.write(final)
  sys.stdout.flush()
  list[x] = old
  time.sleep(0.1)
```