# Python: print a table and change its content

Tags: python, packet-sniffers

I want to print out a table that shows all the wireless networks around (sniffing beacon frames). But I want the content of the table to be changeable. For instants:

- change amount of received frames
- remove the access point if it's no longer in range

I tested some modules, such as terminaltables etc., but I can just print out the table and leave it as it is, without changing anything.

```
from scapy.all import *

def pckt_hndlr(pckt):
    if pckt.haslayer(Dot11):
        if pckt.type == 0 and pckt.subtype == 8:

             # PRINT THE INFORMATION OF THE PACKETS IN A TABLE

sniff(iface='wlan0', prn=pckt_hndlr, store=0)
```

If I add the table to `pckt_hndlr` it's going to be printed out each time I receive a packet.

Comment: what you need is to redraw the table every time. there are several examples you can find online. Something like this might inspire you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122385/dynamic-terminal-printing-with-python

Comment: Thank you! But I think the table would flash and blink when redrawing it. I'm just wondering how airodump-ng is able to do it so smoothly, it's exactly what I want. Is it because Python doesn't support that?

Comment: you mean flash and blink because of delays between flushing and redraw? how long does it take to draw your entire table once?

Comment: It doesn't take long, but it's quite noticeable..

Comment: then curses/ncurses it is, draw the table then individually fill it. it is considerably more complex. but it also mentioned in the same link.

Comment: Yes, I saw this. I'm going to try this out! Thank you for helping me.

Comment: no problem :) :)